# ViewControllers strange view, when I create segue

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'm new to swift and I don't know how do the segues exactly work. I just want to be able to go for example from the RegisterViewController to the LoginViewController. but when I create a segue from register to login all the objects in all view controllers move. They return to a normal position when I click the NavigationController, but if I click on RegisterViewController the view again spoils. The problem is only in storyboard, when I run my application everything seems to be okay. How can I fix this problem?

I have read some articles about segues in swift, but I did not find any information connected to my issue.

This is the view before i add a segue from the RegisterViewController to the LoginViewController:

[image]

And this is after:

[image]